# starting or restarting logical replication in postgres when tables out of sync

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

I have a table in two databases called test.  I was able to make a row in the source database and have it replicated in the target database.  But then I deleted the row in the target database.  How do I get the row back?  What if it's a million rows in each table and I want to synchronize between the two tables because for whatever reason there are repeat in the target database etc.

Here's what I did

```
create role sub247 with login password 'fakepassword' 
     replication;
```

SELECT * FROM pg_stat_replication;

alter user sub247 login connection limit 18;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO sub247;

CREATE TABLE public.test
(
    test text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    test2 bigint
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.test
    OWNER to postgres;
insert into test (test,test2)
values ('a',1)

alter table test replica identity full;
create publication pub247b for table test;

and then on the target database

```
create subscription sub247b connection 'host=facebook.com dbname=247 user=sub247 password=fakepassword port=5432' publication pub247b;
```

and then after some time...
delete from test.

Now, how do i synchronize test on the target database again

Comment: If you cannot get the deleted data back, you'll have to start from scratch with logical replication.

Comment: I think I found the answer.  You do alter publication pub247 drop table [table] and then alter publication add table [table].  Is that what you mean by start from scratch with logical replication?

Comment: I guess that should work.

Comment: I guess you should use
`ALTER SUBSCRIPTION sub247b REFRESH PUBLICATION;`
[doc_pg10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-alterpublication.html)